# Antonym of peruse

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm aware that 'peruse' might be considered a contranym. [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peruse) lists the contrasting senses in the order:

> 1. to read through with thoroughness or care: *to peruse a report.*
> 2. to read in an often desultory way.

From the AHDEL usage note at the link, the Webster's sense 1 is the traditionally accepted one, but the second sense is growing in popularity and acceptability.

Recently a friend of mine (who tutors students for the SAT and GRE) said that there was another equally cool word, say *W*,  whose 'non-traditional' definition is the 'opposite' of 'non-traditional' *peruse* and whose traditional definition is the 'opposite' of traditional *peruse*.  That is, *W*'s original and primary sense is "to look over or through in a casual or cursory manner" but its increasingly common ("informal") definition is "to examine or consider with attention and in detail".

Does anyone know what the word W is?

Comment: 'Scan' also has the dual senses. From [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scan) (with reformatting): **scan** v.tr. 1a. To look at carefully or thoroughly, especially in search of something; examine: The sailor scanned the horizon for signs of land. b. To look over quickly or read hastily: I scanned the newspaper while eating breakfast. >> However, none of AHDEL, Collins and RHK Webster's consider either sense informal, and all consider the 'scrutinise' sense the principal one. // Would you mind if I edited your question?

Comment: While I doubt many use it, 'curse' is used here.  (our custom verb of cursory).  Go with scan.

Comment: @sumelic W is just a place holder and doesn't necessarily mean it starts with W

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't mind if you edit the question so long as the edit doesn't stray from my original question.

Comment: @Squirtle ~ Does your friend not know the answer either, or is he playing games with you? ;) just curious

Comment: I assume your attempts with a thesaurus have beared no fruit? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/scrutinize ; http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dissect ; http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/explore ; http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/probe

Comment: I have just received "...a complimentary ***perusal*** copy ..." of a piano tutor book.  I shall be reading it carefully.  Perusal with the sense of '*glance over/through*' or '*scan*' seems like a misuse due to it sounding like another word with that sense.  Trouble is, I haven't, yet, brought that other word to mind...

Answer (score 1):

**look (something) over** (informal)

[thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+over)

> to examine something carefully

**look over (something)** (formal)

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-over-sth)

> to quickly examine something

The difference in formality seems to be the placement of the *something* in the phrase. To *look over something* seems like what you'd say in a professional setting (e.g. "Look over these files"), but to *look something over* seems more casual.

---

alternate:

**look-over** (formal)

[Oxford English dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/look-over)

> (noun) A quick inspection of something

As for the informal variant of 'look-over', I suppose it would be possible to use it in a context of an in-depth inspection of something ("Give it a look-over"). But I don't think there would be an official source for that.